# Errors during reading from text file

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code that able to read data from txt file(Task ). I did it but the problem is that the result is not as expected because

```
at={3,5,7,10,15} 
bt={2,6,8,16,22}!!!
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void two_arrays_txt_file(float at[5], float bt[5], float zt[], float mt[]);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    float zt[5]; // the result value 
    float mt[5];
    float at[5];
    float bt[5];
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("2arrays.txt");
    two_arrays_txt_file(at, bt, zt, mt);
    printf("(with a function  two ararays from txt file) \n adding z1 = %8.2f, z2 = %8.2f\t,z3=%f\t,z4=%f \tk=%f\n", zt[0], zt[1], zt[2], zt[3], zt[4]);
    printf("(with a function of productof two ararays from txt file) \n Multiplying mm1 = %8.2f, mm2 = %8.2f, mm3 = %8.2f, mm4 = %8.2f, mm5 = %8.2f", mt[0], mt[1], mt[2], mt[3], mt[4]);
    fin.close();
    cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
    getchar();
}
void two_arrays_txt_file(float at[5], float bt[5], float zt[], float mt[]) { // Task 6
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        zt[i] = at[i] + bt[i];
        mt[i] = at[i] * bt[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you read from the file?

Comment: I created a file named "arrays.txt" and tried to red it using  ifstream fin;
    fin.open("2arrays.txt");

Comment: What is the contents of the file? What is your actual output from this program? What is the expected output?

Comment: @BasheerAl_Hadeethi You need to show the code you are using to read from the file.  Right now all you are showing us is using an uninitialized array which will always produce garbage.  Please **[edit]** the code into your question.

Comment: That doesn't actually *read* anything from the file, that's just you opening the file so it *could* be read. There no input (e.g. `>>`) operations, no `getline` calls, no `read` calls, nothing to actually read from the file. Maybe you need to read [a `std::istream` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)? Maybe you should try to search for a file input/output tutorial?

Comment: the txt file contain the array at,bt that contain the values above.

Comment: Yes but you are saying the `bt` has the wrong values.  How are we supposed to tell you why it has the wrong values when you don't show the code?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thx, I will check it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg no, I mean that I have at and bt in the text file and I wanna make adding and multiplying in my code but the result zt and mt are wrong.

Comment: @BasheerAl_Hadeethi If your file contains "at={3,5,7,10,15}", that's not C++ code. It's just a piece of text. Opening the file will not read it and magically execute that line as if it were C++ code. I think you need to review some file handling (and C++) fundamentals.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for your very supportive comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how your text file is but you are not reading anything from the text file you are just opening the text file and closing it.
Here what you  should do

```
 #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
 using namespace std;
void two_arrays_txt_file(float at[5], float bt[5], float zt[], float mt[]);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    float zt[5]; // the result value 
   float mt[5];
   float at[5];
   float bt[5];
   ifstream fin;
   fin.open("2arrays.txt");
   fin>>at[1] ;//  //you have to take input from file like this
   /* since i dont know that in what way numbers are stored in file so i        cannot tell you the exact way to take input and get output the way you want it.*/
two_arrays_txt_file(at, bt, zt, mt);
printf("(with a function  two ararays from txt file) \n adding z1 = %8.2f, z2 = %8.2f\t,z3=%f\t,z4=%f \tk=%f\n", zt[0], zt[1], zt[2], zt[3], zt[4]);
printf("(with a function of productof two ararays from txt file) \n Multiplying mm1 = %8.2f, mm2 = %8.2f, mm3 = %8.2f, mm4 = %8.2f, mm5 = %8.2f", mt[0], mt[1], mt[2], mt[3], mt[4]);
fin.close();
cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
getchar();
 }
void two_arrays_txt_file(float at[5], float bt[5], float zt[], float mt[]) {       
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {
     zt[i] = at[i] + bt[i];
     mt[i] = at[i] * bt[i];
 }
```

}

Comment: the text file contain the following: at={3,5,7,10,15}, bt={2,6,8,16,22}

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading anything from the file in the code snippet you have shown here. in.open() will only open the file. You need to read from it

You can do it by in>>'variable name'

Comment: I did it, and read about but I cant understand it?